# How to trigger an action when a certain div is viewed/scrolled to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some divs, I need to trigger an action (float another div or fire an alert for example) when a certain div is viewed or scrolled to.. What is the best approach to do so?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by "viewed" I have no idea - but here is how you would do it when the user puts their mouse over the `div`:

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();
    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView(myelement)) {
        // in view
    } else {
        // not in view
    }
});
```

Credit to [Is there a way to detect when an HTML element is hidden from view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769701/is-there-a-way-to-detect-when-an-html-element-is-hidden-from-view)

Comment: by viewed I meant scrolled to/ came into the view.. Unfortunately I tried this but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [Bullseye jQuery plugin](http://static.pixeltango.com/jQuery/Bullseye/) which adds adds `enterviewport` and `leaveviewport` events to elements.